# my info was compromised

Tags: fraud

My ssn,dob,mother's maiden,phone number, and address were compromised and I am worried that some bad people now have all the afore mentioned information. My question is what could criminals do with this information?

Comment: Your SSN is really the only truly private piece of information there. Have you heard of identity theft?

Answer (score 1):

Criminals could potentially use the information that was compromised to steal your identity.  They could then use this information to take out loans or open lines of credit in your name.

To mitigate this, you may want to lock your credit report.  Congress passed a law in 2018 making it free to do so.  By locking your credit report, banks and lenders will be unable to view your credit report without your authorization.  Without being able to view your credit report, they'll be unlikely to give a loan or line of credit to someone impersonating you.

For more info, see the page below on the FTC site about freezing your credit report:
http://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0497-credit-freeze-faqs

Links to pages at the web sites of the three major credit bureaus for freezing your credit report:
http://www.experian.com/consumer/security_freeze.html
http://www.transunion.com/securityfreeze
http://www.equifax.com/help/credit-freeze/en_cp